# Error QtCreator.exe - Entry point not found on windows 8.1

Tags: qt, qt-creator, windows-8.1

I installed Qt creator with offline installer: *qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.2.exe*
I'm using  windows 8.1 enterprise, also i installed VS13 and it's working without problem but
When i try to Open QtCreator, encounter this error:

> The procedure entry point free not be located in the dynamic link
>   library C:\Qt\Qt5.11.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\ExtensionSystem4.dll
>   how to hix it?
>   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I installed update *KB2932046* and *KB2919355* and after reboot i tried install updates online! It fixed automatically!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this means your executable does not have access to that dll. You may have to manually copy it to the directory where your executable is.

Comment: I checked that. the dll file already exist near executable, but I temporary removed the dll file but the error doesn't changed. I mean it's looks no different that .dll exist or not!